# Getting error for auto increment fields when inserting records without specifying columns

Tags: postgresql

We're in process of converting over from SQL Server to Postgres.  I have a scenario that I am trying to accommodate.  It involves inserting records from one table into another, WITHOUT listing out all of the columns.  I realize this is not recommended practice, but let's set that aside for now.

```
drop table if exists pk_test_table;

create table public.pk_test_table
(
    recordid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name text
);

--example 1: works and will insert a record with an id of 1
insert into pk_test_table values(default,'puppies');

--example 2: fails
insert into pk_test_table
select first_name from person_test;
```

Error I receive in the second example:

> column "recordid" is of type integer but expression is of type
>   character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the
>   expression.

The `default` keyword will tell the database to grab the next value.
Is there any way to utilize this keyword in the second example? Or some way to tell the database to ignore auto-incremented columns and just them be populated like normal?
I would prefer to *not* use a subquery to grab the next "id".
This functionality works in SQL Server and hence the question.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: And what is the error message ?

Comment: @Houari updated to include error.  Appears like it is just trying to insert the text into the recordid column.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't list column names, you should instead use the `DEFAULT` keyword, as you've done in the simple insert example. This won't work with a in `insert into ... select ...`.

For that, you need to invoke `nextval`. A subquery is not required, just:

```
insert into pk_test_table
select nextval('pk_test_table_id_seq'), first_name from person_test;
```

You do need to know the sequence name. You could get that from `information_schema` based on the table name and inferring its primary key, using a function that takes just the table name as an argument. It'd be ugly, but it'd work. I don't think there's any way around needing to know the table name.

Comment: Couldn't you just specify the DEFAULT field setting in the Table definition? Then would you need to specify each field?

Comment: @FastEngy Yes, if you can provide a column-list for the `insert`, but this user's framework or tools are apparently not capable of that. For some reason.

Comment: @CraigRinger I agree this is an option.  It's a bit more searching and digging than what we're looking to do in our scenario.  We are dealing with ~800 audit triggers from SQL Server and trying to simplify our postgres equivalent.

Comment: @Airn5475 Why not just write a single generic trigger with dynamic SQL generation? You can always hand-write a few if performance becomes an issue on busy tables.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting value into the first column, but you need to add a value in the second position.

Therefore you can use `INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES(value)` syntax.
Since you need to fetch values from another table, you have to remove `VALUES` and put the subquery there.

```
insert into pk_test_table(name) 
select first_name from person_test;
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I understand that this works and is recommended.  However, as mentioned, we are dealing with a bit different of a situation and need to allow inserts without listing out the columns.

Comment: I think that's the only way to do this in PostgreSQL. You have to list out the columns, otherwise you have to remove the serial attribute from the primary key, create a sequence. For every insert call `nextval(sequence)` in `select nextval(sequence), frist_name from person_test`.
At the end, alter the primary key field and add `nextval(sequence)` as default value

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way via a separate function- though I think I'm getting around the issue via the table level having the DEFAULT settings on a per field basis.

```
create table public.pk_test_table
(
    recordid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pk_test_table_id_seq'),
    name text,
    field3 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 64,
    null_field_if_not_set integer,
    CONSTRAINT pk_test_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("recordid")
);
```

With function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_pk_test_table() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
    INSERT INTO pk_test_table (name) 
    SELECT first_name FROM person_test;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

Then just execute the function via a SELECT FROM func_pk_test_table();

Notice it hasn't had to specify all the fields- as long as constraints allow it.